# How do I have a no render material that still receives shadows in Three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to create a "transparent" material in the sense that it does not render and leaves an empty alpha region on the screen so you can see what is behind the canvas but I also want the material to receive shadows and still render them.

I have an experimental [JSFiddle page](https://jsfiddle.net/tyduptyler13/evcrhygq/) for this exact purpose.

I have only managed to get the semi see-through effect working but not the shadows properly. The orange you see in the material is actually an orange div behind the render. The render required a black billboard behind the object to keep the background black and to display what I really want. Rendering the plane with my custom material allows the render to add an alpha to the target permitting it to show things behind the canvas. My goal is to allow this but with a shadow on that same material, masking the element behind it.

The core code permitting the effect is shown below:

```
var plane = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(10, 10, 1, 1);
var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    color:'gray',
    blending: THREE.NoBlending,
    opacity: 0,
    side: THREE.DoubleSide
});
```

I have also tried Additive Blending but it had no substantial effect.

I am wondering if I will have to do this with a simple shader that changes high values to alpha and leaves low values.

**Update:**
I have a almost working version of what I am looking for [here](https://jsfiddle.net/tyduptyler13/5zc1Lbnr/2/). The finishing touch would be adding a shadow map to the object for my desired effect. However, I want the shadows to occlude the background behind the scene. I plan to mix CSS3D and WebGL but would prefer if I could maintain my shadows. (Sadly the content I plan to have as CSS3D won't easily be converted to a texture/object).
[image: Test of shadow map]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be able to achieve the hole effect using `opacity: 0` and `transparent: true`.

Comment: I am happy/honored to be helped by the guy who made Three.

Comment: Sorry for taking forever to respond. Ditched the idea temporarily. Decided I would need a special shader to get the exact effect I wanted. Thank you for the suggestion though. It got me the closest to the answer I wanted!

Comment: I'm trying to create an effect, I think, similar to the original question author. I'm looking to create and "invisible" floor that still receives shadows. I've tried the  opacity:0 and transparent:true mentioned above without success. I've posted the code here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/134791/shadow/index.html Is this effect possible?